# How to set margin using print to file (pdf)

Tags: 16.04, printing, pdf

I just learned about the feature to print to a PDF and I love it.

[image: Print to PDF dialog]

The only challenge I am having is when printing a web page, the header is printed on top of the text.

[image: Overwriting text]

I have looked at the options and see that I can have it print nothing in that area. However, what I really want is to print the header but increase the margin so there is room for the text and the header. I do not see an option for that.

[image: Print to PDF options]

Is there a way to increase the margin when printing to a PDF?

Comment: Where is this option found?

Comment: Ctrl+P brings up the initial dialog. I am using it inside of Firefox but I believe it is a system-level feature.

Comment: Tried here and I think it's printer specific

Comment: But I did not add a "print to file" printer. That seems to come with the system.

Answer (score 1):

It is on the "Page Setup" tab.

There, you have "Paper Size", click on that combobox and scroll to the last item (easier if you just press the "END" key): **"Manage Custom Sizes"**
There you will have the margins!

You can also give the custom size a name, just click on the custom name to change it.
Here, my printer only works with bigger margins, so I created this:
"A4 with good margins", all in mm now:
top 15, bottom 15, left 10, right 10.

This works on Ubuntu 20.04 at least.

Answer (score 0):

File -> Print Preview -> on the top left second button from the left ("Page settings"(?))

Here you should be able to select the Papersize. Create your own custom new papersize with bigger margins.

(I have different language settings, so I hope my translations above are ok)